# How to filter tasks in MS Project, using VBA, and with multiple conditions?

Tags: vba, ms-project, vba7, vba6

I have a line of VBA code that creates a filter with one condition, this works well:

```
FilterEdit Name:="temp", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, FieldName:="Resource Names", Test:="contains", Value:='Electician', ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=False
```

The equivalent popup window would be:

Filter Definition Popup for One Condition

[image: 1]

However I want to filter for rows containing that string AND have an outline level greater than 2.

The filter popup for this is:

Filter Definition Popup for Two Conditions

[image: 2]

The filter popup would work well if I only needed it once, however the conditions I use change dynamically so I need to define it using VBA.

The [Microsoft Documentation for FilterEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.filteredit) mentions the Operation argument but there is no example of how to use it.

I tried stringing together several arguments in the function but it did not work:

```
FilterEdit Name:="temp", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, FieldName:="Resource Names", Test:="contains", Value:='Electician', Operation:="And", FieldName:="Outline Level", Test:="is less than or equal to", Value:=2, ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating multiple criteria in a filter requires additional calls to the [FilterEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.filteredit) method as such:

```
Sub MakeFilter()
    
    FilterEdit Name:="temp", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True _
        , FieldName:="Resource Names", Test:="contains", Value:="Electrician" _
        , ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=False
        
    FilterEdit Name:="temp", TaskFilter:=True, FieldName:="", NewFieldName:="Outline Level" _
        , Test:="is less than or equal to", Value:="2", Operation:="And"

End Sub
```

Note that Value is always a string and that optional arguments do not always need to be included if the default value is desired (see documentation in link above).

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked great.

Future readers: make note of needing to use ``FieldName:="", NewFieldName:==`` in the second criteria row.